# Datetime in Rails query using .select

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have two rails models, `MyParent` and `MyChild`.

I'm trying to build a query using the rails `.select()` methods to efficiently extra a large number of rows for the database.

I want to pull back a number of columns from across the two tables, but when I reference a column which is of type datetime (or timestamp) but not in the original model, it is returned as a string.

Eg:

```
irb(main)> MyChild.select(['created_at as child_date', 'created_at']).first.child_date.class
=> String #Bad!!!
irb(main)> MyChild.select(['created_at as child_date', 'created_at']).first.created_at.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone  #YAY!!!!
```

I first encountered this problem when attempted to pull a datetime from the MyParent table using `joins()`.

How can I tell rails that I want `child_date` as a ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone object?

I'm using the latest version of Rails 3.2.

Comment: Can't you do that? `CAST(child_date AS DATE)`

Comment: It already is a date though. The problem seems to be that Rails can't figure out how to convert the sql result without info from ActiveRecord.

Comment: It still returns string.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that I could come up with was to cast the resulting date back into a TimeWithZone object

```
Time.zone.parse(MyChild.select(['created_at as child_date']).first.child_date)
# returns a ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone object
```